# How to update model with associations in SailJS

Tags: javascript, sails.js

I am trying to work with Models with associations. I have three models:

**PosProductCategory.js**

```
module.exports = {
    schema : true,
    attributes: {
        name : {type : 'string', required : true },
        desc : {type : 'text', required : true },
        // assets
        products : { collection : 'PosProduct', via : 'category' },
        productsCustomize : { collection : 'PosCustomProduct', via : 'category' },
        display : { model : 'CmsProductCategory' },
        // available spec & template attribute
        availableSpecification : { type : 'array' },
        templateAttribute : { type : 'array' },
        // store referrer
        store : { model : 'SystemStore' }
    }
};
```

**PosProduct.js**

```
module.exports = {
    schema : true,
    attributes: {
        name          : { type : 'string', required   : true },
        desc          : { type : 'text' },
        basePrice     : { type : 'integer' , required : true },
        // category
        category      : { model : 'PosProductCategory'},
        // tags
        // { "text": {string} }
        tags          : { collection : 'PosProductTag', via : 'products', dominant: true},
        // attributes
        attributes    : { type : 'object' },
        // specification
        specification : { type : 'object' },
        // materials (donwlodable material / attachment)
        // { name : {string}, file: {string}, notes : {text} }
        materials     : {type : 'array'},
        // publishment
        published     : { type : 'boolean', defaultsTo: false },
        // assets
        display       : { model : 'CmsProduct' },
        // store referrer
        store         : { model : 'SystemStore' }
    }
};
```

**PosCustomProduct.js**

```
module.exports = {
    schema : true,
    attributes: {
        name            : { type : 'string', required   : true },
        basePrice       : { type : 'integer' , required : true },
        //category
        category        : { model : 'PosProductCategory'},
        //variant
        attributes      : { type : 'object' },
        //gambar setiap sisi
        materials       : { type : 'object' },
        // publishment
        published       : { type : 'boolean', defaultsTo: false },
        // assets
        display         : { model : 'CmsCustomProduct' },
        // store referrer
        store           : { model : 'SystemStore' }
    }
```

If I run using **sails lift**, I got an error **Error: Trying to associate a collection attribute to a model that doesn't have Foregn Key. poscustomproduct category is trying to reference a foreign key in poscustomproduct** . I was try to fix its but its still got an error. So how to fix my model?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to associate a model with no way of referencing the relationship, For example you have your "master" table but your "secondary" table has no way of telling who the items belong to...

http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/associations/one-to-many